# PDO Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Im having a strange issue with a select with PDO, so I came here to ask for your help.
I have this code below and Im getting this **error**:

```
    Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: 
parameter was not defined in  `$verifyUser->execute();`
```

Somebody there have an ideia why this can be happening?

**My Php Code:**

```
if(!$_SESSION['result'])
 {
    header('Location: index.php');
 }
else   
{
    $userId = $_SESSION['result']['id'];                
    $verifyUser = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM aadmins where id = :userId");  
    $verifyUser->bindValue(":id", $userId);  
    $verifyUser->execute();
    $num_rows = $verifyUser->rowCount();
    $result = $verifyUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: Your placeholder is `:userId` but you are binding `:id`. Bind `:userId` in `bindValue()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `:userId` in SQL query, while in bindValue you are using `:id`.

```
$verifyUser = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM aadmins where id = :userId");  
$verifyUser->bindValue(":id", $userId);
```

But it should be the same in query and bindvalue.

```
$verifyUser = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM aadmins where id = :id");  
$verifyUser->bindValue(":id", $userId);
```

Comment: Thanks...it was the problem! I dont know how I didnt see that, I think I've got the fried head after so many hours lol! Thanks :)

Comment: So obvious when you see

Comment: Great, this worked perfect for me, thanks, couldn't nail this on the head till now.